# Why does jQuery change() method enable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following sequence of method calls on a select element set the initial selected option to the one with a value-5, then causes the "change" event to be triggered.

```
$('#abCategory')
.val(5)
.change()
.prop('disabled', true)
;
```

For some reason the element is not being disabled as would be expected with the .prop() method call. If the change() method is removed the element is disabled.

Why is this happening? How can I fire the change() event and also disable the element?

Comment: [I don't reproduce this behavior](http://jsbin.com/eDOQIDaV/1/) : the input is disabled.

Comment: Are you having an old version of jQuery where `.prop` does not exist? Or you have a place where you have bound an event to the `change` event?

Comment: @Niels - that was my initial thought too.. but OP says it works when `.change` is removed which is weird.

Comment: Than what ever is bound to change must be enabling it... Did you look at what listens for change on that element and see what it does?

Comment: I would imagine you've already checked your developer console for errors. Right? I mean an error thrown in the handler would prevent `.prop()` from running, but certainly you've already checked for that.

Comment: Try this before the trigger of the change `.unbind("change")` so we know if the `change` event occurs the issue.

Comment: If you could setup a minimal jsfiddle that will demonstrate your problem and post the js/HTML here for us that would be best.

Comment: After some additional research I found there is a problem elsewhere in the code causing the behavior. Thanks for your input which led to me tracking it down.

Comment: @ChrisP Please answer your own question then. It may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the above problem was an errant jQuery selector elsewhere in the component that included this select element. The above code works correctly when that was corrected.